# Cordova can't add plugin: Error: Cannot find module 'unorm'

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to add a plugin to my cordova app, but I get an error saying "The platform "ios" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. ios not supported."

```
node --version
v9.2.0

cordova --version
8.0.0
```

Here is the command I'm running

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appinfo
```

And the complete output:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-appinfo" for ios
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module 'unorm'
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-appinfo': Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (The platform "ios" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. ios not supported.)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:140:19)
    at EventEmitter.module.exports.emit (/Users/james/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/events.js:71:17)
    at Object.getPlatformApiFunction (/Users/james/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/util.js:499:20)
    at Object.getPlatformApi (/Users/james/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms.js:55:25)
    at handleInstall (/Users/james/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:593:29)
    at /Users/james/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:357:28
    at _fulfilled (/Users/james/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/james/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/james/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /Users/james/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
(node:35697) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Unhandled error. (The platform "ios" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. ios not supported.)
(node:35697) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm certain this is a valid Cordova project and the iOS platform seems to work fine (I can build and run on an iPhone).

Comment: This problem appeared when the plugins folder was checked into the repository. Removing the platform and adding it again solved this. (We deleted the folder from git GIT repository and added these folders to the .gitignore again, but still we have to add and remove the platform every time.. still don't know why)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into same error after attempting to update ios platform. 
It turns out there was some corruption in the node_modules download cache.
I was able resolve this by trying a second time:

```
cordova platform rm ios 
cordova platform add ios@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this and the currently accepted answer (remove then add the ios platform) didn't work for me. Instead it looks like the problem is with the nodejs version. Downgrading from node 16 to node 12 made it work. Got this from [this answer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-find-module-unorm/204695/3). I use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) so for me it was easy as:

```
nvm install 12 --lts
nvm use 12
```